# Assertion `in' failed - c++

Tags: c++, assertion

The following is part of client program for a fraction class.  I wrote the class and now am testing it with the given client program.  When I try to run it, I get this error:

> Assertion `'in'` failed.

Code:

```cpp
bool eof(ifstream& in);

cout << "\n----- Now reading Fractions from file\n";
ifstream in("fraction.data");
assert(in);
while (!eof(in)) {
    Fraction f;
    if (in.peek() == '#') {
        in.ignore(128, '\n');                    //skip this line, it's a comment
    } else {
        in >> f;
        cout << "Read fraction = " << f << endl;
    }
```

As a relative beginner to C++, I don't really understand what this part of the code is supposed to be doing:

```cpp
ifstream in("fraction.data");
assert(in);
```

And when I try to debug and I get to that point, it says:

> No source available for `"__kernel_vsyscall() at 0x12e416"`

So yeah, in conclusion I'm pretty clueless about why this happening :P

EDIT:  Here are the include statements

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "fraction.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Does the file `fraction.data` exist in the same directory as the program?

Comment: @KerrekSB wouldn't `fraction.data` actually need to exist in the working directory (which obviously could also be the programs directory)?

Comment: The error message is probably because there are no public symbols for the `assert` function.

Comment: `assert(x)` basically says "crash if `x` is false" and only works in debug builds.  Basically it means the stream could not load your file for some reason.

Comment: @KerrekSB:  Yes, `fraction.data` is in the same directory

Comment: @sq1020: If you're using MSVC, right click the project->properties->Configuration Properties->debugging.  Set the "Working Directory" to that same folder.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  I'm using eclipse...perhaps it's similar?

Comment: @Mooing Duck: The statement, "No source avaiable..." comes when you single step, **using a debugger**, and try to step into a function that has no source code or there is no source code for the function(s) handling the error / exception.  Reread the post, search for the words "when I try to debug".

Comment: @sq1020: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_run_arg.htm (corrected the link.  Stupid eclipse site)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I misread the comment as symbols missing at compile time.  My bad.  You're comment was correct.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews:  can you elaborate on "no public symbols for the assert function"?  Thanks!

Comment: @sq1020:  When you build a program with the "debug" option, it provides addition information, often called symbols, to assist in debugging.  Some addition items include line number, function name, and filename.  These items are not necessary for "release" execution and make the binary executable larger.  Many times, run-time libraries do not have symbols for common functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it.  I just need to move my "fraction.data" file to main project directory.  Before, I had it in the source folder within the directory.

Answer (score 2):

The assert() fails if the expression evaluates to false.

```
assert(in)
```

fails because in (the input file) evaluates to false. Your code is unable to open a file called "fraction.data". If in were a valid input file stream, assert(in) would pass, and you'd go on about your business.

Short answer -> "File not found" or "Can't create a file here".

Comment: any ideas on it can't find the "fraction.data" file?  It's in the same director as the client program.

Answer (score 0):

`assert` is a runtime check that verifies its argument is true.  In this case, your file is not valid.